# JSON stringify outputs empty object for not empty object

Tags: javascript

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/11n8hL1y/11/)

Why does JSON.stringify produce an empty object?

```
window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
function updateDimensions(){
    var node = document.getElementById('sample');
    var windowDimensions = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    var dimensions = node.getBoundingClientRect();

  console.log('dimensions', dimensions);//dimensions is ClientRect {top: X, right: ...} 

var result = ' dimensions: ' + JSON.stringify(dimensions)
             + ' windowDimensions: ' + JSON.stringify(windowDimensions); 

  console.log(result);//now dimensions is {}
}

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="sample">
  Hello World
</div>

#sample {
 padding: 20px;
 max-height: 380px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 max-width: 150px;
 border: solid blue;
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Which call of stringify?

Comment: @StefanoNardo - Its noted in the comments.  the second console.log value for dimensions.  Though, this is a duplicate so the point is now moot.